# Flurry Ads not displaying

Tags: ios, objective-c, ads, flurry

I have [flurry](/questions/tagged/flurry) ads in my app.

Initially while integrating Flurry, it showed the bottom banner ad, but now it shows error instead and I don't know where went wrong.

Here's the error message:

> [Error Domain=FlurryAds Code=117 "FlurryAds: Ad request to server
>   failed." UserInfo=0x7f82c956e0c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=FlurryAds: Ad
>   request to server failed.}]

**Sample Code:**

```
[Flurry startSession:@"API KEY"]; 
[FlurryAds initialize:_window.rootViewController]; 
[Flurry setBackgroundSessionEnabled:YES]; 
[Flurry setEventLoggingEnabled:YES]; 
//In view controller: viewwillappear: 
[FlurryAds setAdDelegate:self];
 flurryContainer=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,600,330,50)]; size:BANNER_BOTTOM]; 
[self.view addsubview:flurryContainer]; 
[FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VC" view:flurryContainer viewController:self size:BANNER_BOTTOM];
```

Comment: Ad request to server failed

Comment: Can you paste some code in?

Comment: can anyone suggest me a solution for this error

Comment: In Appdelegte: under didfinish launchingwithoptions:   [Flurry startSession:@"API KEY"];
    [FlurryAds initialize:_window.rootViewController];
    [Flurry setBackgroundSessionEnabled:YES];
     [Flurry setEventLoggingEnabled:YES];
       In view controller:   viewwillappear:  [FlurryAds setAdDelegate:self];
 flurryContainer=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,600,330,50)];
size:BANNER_BOTTOM]; [self.view addsubview:flurryContainer];
        [FlurryAds fetchAndDisplayAdForSpace:@"BANNER_MAIN_VC" view:flurryContainer viewController:self size:BANNER_BOTTOM];

Comment: @Damian,Till now I don't know about the error,Flurry ads is not displaying in my app.